# PHP filter_input were validatio flags are an enum?

Tags: php, enums, filtering

Looked around but didn't see this anywhere, the basic question is, can I use a `filter_input_array` were the value of one of my keys is an enum (think mysql enum), protocode would be something like this.

```
print_r(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    'CanBeFooOrBar' => [
        'filter'   => FILTER_VALIDATE_ENUM, 
        'options'  => ['foo', 'bar'],
    ]
]));
```

If this is possible, what is my filter, and if not, what would be the best way to replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific list/enum filter.
The closest you get is [`FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) with something like:

```
print_r(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    'CanBeFooOrBar' => [
        'filter'   => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
        'options'  => ["regexp" => "/^(foo|bar)$/"],
    ]
]));
```

Personally I'm using [something](http://fossil.include-once.org/hybrid7/wiki/input) more fancy, which simplifies it to:

```
print $_POST->in_array("CanBeFooOrBar", "foo,bar");
```